# Automatically access my Google Analytics and display chart publicly on my website

Tags: javascript, html, api, charts, analytics

I'm having some difficulties in figuring out the best way to do this:

Using Google Analytics API, or similar Google API, I would like to track a user's activity from the moment they access the page until they reach an end page, which is gonna show them back some charts with THEIR activity on my website. (Nothing too detailed, just how long they've been on each page, how many session etc.)

So far, I've managed follow the [Embed API example](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/) to access THE USER's Google Analytics account and draw a chart by asking for permission, however when it comes to showing data from MY account I just can't seem to figure it out.

I want my website to automatically use my account (or service account) and draw some charts from my google analytics data and show it to every user.

What would be the best way to approach this? I've read something about access tokens but I don't know if that's the solution. Moreover, my hosting is a shared host and I don't think it allows installing Python Modules like in [this example](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/).

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the user your data, you will have to perform the authentication on the server side. There is no way around this. It is after all, your account's data that they are accessing.

If you are unable to install Google's client library, you need to:

1. Get an access token using cURL ([see how here](http://www.daimto.com/google-authentication-with-curl/))
2. Use that access token to perform server side authentication for the user ([see how here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/))

The user should now be able to access your site without logging in, and see YOUR data.

Comment: Cheers for the help. I'll look into it and see if I can get it to work.